# How can I get a column value from another table outside of UNION ALL?

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

In my SQL I am getting transactions relating to a user and a business. However, I also need to get the name of the business. It is found in column business_name under table Businesses. In my example SQL, I would want to get the business name for business_id=1. My current code works aside from not getting the business name.

```
(SELECT TRUNCATE(code_reward_amount, 2) AS amount, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(code_redeemed_date) AS date, 0 AS action_number
FROM CodesRedeemed
WHERE code_redeemed_by_user_id=191 AND code_business_id=1)
UNION ALL
(SELECT TRUNCATE(action_amount, 2) AS amount, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(action_date) AS date, action_number
FROM BusinessAccountActions
WHERE action_user_id=191 AND action_business_id=1)
ORDER BY date DESC
LIMIT 100
```

In my second code attempt, it does get the business name, however, it is not efficient to do the select in every row since the business name would be the same for each row. How can I do it once and apply it to each row? Perhaps somewhere outside of the UNION ALL? Here is my working code, however, I would like to optimize it so it doesn't SELECT from Businesses for the business_name in every single row (since the business_name is guaranteed to be the same for all rows since they share the same business_id).

```
(SELECT TRUNCATE(code_reward_amount, 2) AS amount, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(code_redeemed_date) AS date, 0 AS action_number, (SELECT business_name FROM Businesses WHERE business_id=1) AS business_name
FROM CodesRedeemed
WHERE code_redeemed_by_user_id=191 AND code_business_id=1)
UNION ALL
(SELECT TRUNCATE(action_amount, 2) AS amount, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(action_date) AS date, action_number, (SELECT business_name FROM Businesses WHERE business_id=1) AS business_name
FROM BusinessAccountActions
WHERE action_user_id=191 AND action_business_id=1)
ORDER BY date DESC
LIMIT 100
```

[image: Example results for query 2]

business_id would change depending on the business. I am just testing it for business_id 1 right now. How would I optimize (mainly not checking for business_name in every single row)? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `JOIN`.

```
SELECT u.amount, u.date, b.business_name, u.action_number
FROM (
    (SELECT TRUNCATE(code_reward_amount, 2) AS amount, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(code_redeemed_date) AS date, 0 AS action_number
    FROM CodesRedeemed
    WHERE code_redeemed_by_user_id=191 AND code_business_id=1)
    UNION ALL
    (SELECT TRUNCATE(action_amount, 2) AS amount, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(action_date) AS date, action_number
    FROM BusinessAccountActions
    WHERE action_user_id=191 AND action_business_id=1)
    ORDER BY date DESC
    LIMIT 100) AS u
CROSS JOIN Businesses AS b
WHERE b.business_id = 1
```

Comment: Thank you Barmar!

Answer (score 0):

Using a `JOIN` as [Bamar](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45428455/4665) suggested is a perfectly acceptable way to do it, and is how I would most likely do it.

However, you could use a [user defined variable](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/user-variables.html) and replace that additional select with that.

```
 SELECT business_name FROM Businesses WHERE business_id=1 LIMIT 1 INTO @bname;

(SELECT TRUNCATE(code_reward_amount, 2) AS amount, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(code_redeemed_date) AS date, 0 AS action_number, (SELECT business_name FROM Businesses WHERE business_id=1) AS business_name
 FROM CodesRedeemed
 WHERE code_redeemed_by_user_id=191 AND code_business_id=1)
UNION ALL
 (SELECT TRUNCATE(action_amount, 2) AS amount, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(action_date) AS date, action_number, @bname AS business_name
  FROM BusinessAccountActions
  WHERE action_user_id=191 AND action_business_id=1)
  ORDER BY date DESC
  LIMIT 100
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I didn't even know about user defined variables!

Comment: Glad to, help and good to see you are going with Barmar's approach but it's always good to have different tools to help solve a problem.